# IE8 Accordion menu is throwing out some weird bugs

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8, menu

I have an accordion side menu in my latest project that works in all modern browsers properly, apart from ie8.

In Ie8, using the menu and clicking results in random padding and margins to be added and sometimes disappear for no apparent reason. I can't find any bit of jquery code that would potentially cause this to happen which is a pain. Even more confusing is the fact that this doesn't happen in Ie7 =S

Can anyone here replicate this bug, and see what the problem is?

[Project Demo to view in ie8](http://qwibbledesigns.co.uk/preview/control/7/forms.html)

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you why the margins on "#navigation li" seems to disappear, but if I use padding instead it seems to work. Of course you would also have to reduce the bottom-margin on "#navigation li ul" to get the same look as before.